# Find the bname issued to the member named = ' Rahul' . trying to fetch ta data from SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am trying to search the books issued to rahul using joining concept in SQL. but not able to execute it properly.

```
select bname from book_master, member_master, register member_master.mcode = register.mcode and register.bcode=book_master.bcode
where member_master.name = 'rahul';
```

database schema:

Book_master table:

```
 BCODE                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 BNAME                                              VARCHAR2(50)
 AUTHOR                                             VARCHAR2(50)
 PUBLISHER                                          VARCHAR2(50)
 PRICE                                              NUMBER(10,2)
```

register table:

```
 BCODE                                              NUMBER(10)
 COPYNO                                             NUMBER(10)
 MCODE                                              NUMBER(10)
 DATE_OF_ISSUE                                      DATE
 DATE_OF_RETURN                                     DATE
```

member_master table:

```
 MCODE                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(50)
 ADDRESS                                            VARCHAR2(100)
 PHNO                                               NUMBER(10)
```

Comment: You missed WHERE clause after table names in your query.

Comment: Use modern JOIN syntax instead of writing a comma-separated list of tables.

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause is in the wrong place:

```sql
SELECT bname
FROM   book_master,
       member_master,
       register
WHERE  member_master.mcode = register.mcode
AND    register.bcode=book_master.bcode
AND    member_master.name = 'rahul';
```

However, it is better practice to use the modern ANSI/ISO join syntax (rather than the legacy comma-join syntax from 30 years ago):

```sql
SELECT bname
FROM   member_master m
       INNER JOIN register r
       ON (m.mcode = r.mcode)
       INNER JOIN book_master b
       ON (r.bcode = b.bcode)
WHERE  m.name = 'rahul';
```